# Why Twilio Number Flagged or show Unknown?

Tags: php, twilio

I Already Purchase some twilio number for calling purpose to my US client. after some days of calling my client told me that My Number shows as "UNKNOWN". That means my number is flagged now.

My question is

1. Is there any way to know that my number is flagged/spam to my client?
2. why this number is flagged/spam after certain time?

I can't find answer or any link in twilio.

Comment: This is more of a question for [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) as it is not a programming issue. Please contact them, let them know your account SID and the number you are having an issue with and they will be able to help.

Comment: But Some system related to calling- they gave a button, where I click and get result that my number is healthy or spam.

Comment: Honestly, I can’t help you with this. Please contact Twilio support.